# Create Scrolling Excel Chart

Tags: excel, charts, scrollbar

I'm looking to set up a scroll bar in Excel that corresponds to what set of data I use for a chart. I have built a 2-value doughnut chart that acts as a percentage gauge (green section is completed and grey is 100% minus the completed part).

I want to be able to choose what month's data I use for this chart using the scroll bar. All I can seem to find online is how to modify the number of rows and columns that are displayed on a graph rather than actually using the scroller to pick what data to display.

In addition, how would I make it default to the current month? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that is looking for a similar solution, I have figured it out. It works with something called a dynamic range. Use the value of the scrollbar to determine the offset of rows (pick which row of data to use). Then link that dynamic range to your chart in place of where you would select the data.